# Can one conjugate any element in $S_3$ to any other element?

Tags: group-theory

I've come across the following problem from herstein:

> Let $\varphi$ be an automorphism of $S_3$. Show that there is an element $\sigma \in S_3$
>   such that $\varphi(\tau) = \sigma^{-1}\tau\sigma$ for every $\tau \in S_3$.

It seems to me this cannot possibly be true. $S_3$ (in particular) has more then one conjugancy classes.
If the automorphism maps an element from one such class to another, there is no
element that conjugates one element to the other.

Am I missing something, or is the problem simply wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is correctly stated.

To address your arguments, an automorphism maps conjugacy classes to conjugacy classes.  Now $S_{3}$ has three conjugacy classes, of distinct sizes $1, 2, 3$.  It follows that any automorphism maps each conjugacy class onto itself.

Now to the solution of the problem...

Spoiler #1

> Any two distinct involutions generate $S_{3}$.

Spoiler #2

> The group of inner automorphisms of $S_{3}$ acts faithfully on the set of the three involutions of $S_{3}$.

Comment: I'm not (yet) familiar with involutions. Do I take it to mean the question actually asks me to prove that every automorphism of $S_3$ can be written as a conjugation? in that case, the title of my question obviosuly shows I interpreted the question wrongly.

Comment: And Now I understand that my counterexample is false since no automorphism can do that,as you've stated. Thanks.

Comment: yes the problem is to show that there are no automorphisms of $S_3$ other than conjugation. I really did not understand the spoiler 2, in particular the definition of the set of three involutions..

Comment: @palio, consider the two involutions $a = (12)$ and $b = (13)$, and their images $\varphi(a)$ and $\varphi(b)$ under an automorphism $\varphi$. Now there is an inner automorphism $\sigma$ such that $\varphi(a) = \sigma(a)$ and $\varphi(b) = \sigma(b)$, and thus $\varphi = \sigma$.